# How prediction and score works in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to predict output based on set of inputs using linear regression as below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = [[1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 2, 1, 1],
     [1, 3, 1, 1],
     [1, 4, 1, 1],
     [1, 2, 1, 1],
     [1, 3, 1, 1],
     [2, 4, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [2, 1, 1, 1],
     [2, 4, 1, 1],
     [1, 5, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1]]
y = [
    [1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [3],
    [2],
    [1],
    [3],
    [2],
    [1],
    [1],
    [2],
    [1],
    [1],
    [1],
   ]


# Split X and y into X_
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

regression_model = LinearRegression()
regression_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(regression_model.score(X_test, y_test)) # -1.1817143658810325
print(regression_model.predict([[1, 1, 1, 1]]) # [[0.9694444444444441]]
```

I have passed X values as input and expecting y as output

It is displaying the score as negative values and predicted output as  [[0.9694444444444441]] which I am expecting to be 1.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)? Why exactly do you think that a negative score and the predicted output are incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

A linear regression attempts to minimize the **Mean Squared Error** with an optimal hyperplane. Most data is not perfectly linear (including yours), so the predictions will not be perfect. However, they will have as low of an error as possible given the linearity constraint. In your example, there isn't much of a difference between 0.97 and 1.00.

Consider the following linear regression in a smaller number of dimensions to make visualization easier. All the regression does is choose the **line** that fits the data best. That doesn't mean it goes through every point. When you use that line to make a prediction, it will be off by a little bit.
[image: Linear Regression]

The negative score (straight from the documentation) simply means that the model performs worse than if you did nothing but predict the **average value** of your data. Models can perform arbitrarily poorly. In your case, since a linear regression is able to learn such a constant model, this indicates **overfitting** to the training set (likely due to the small sample size). If you scored your train data instead you should get a non-negative answer, and probably one which is positive.

Examining your model a little more closely, you'll notice that anything with a true value of 1 is predicted relatively closely due to the large class imbalance (you have almost twice as many 1's as everything else put together). The 2's are a little worse, and the 3's have a horrendous prediction. A linear model has a tough time making the huge jump from 1's and 2's to 3's for just a couple of points stuck in the middle of the rest of the point cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Musgrave for the detailed explanation. Do you think is there any other Model which can suit my data or simply increasing the size of dataset will solve the issue.

Comment: That would be best dealt with as another question and depends a little on your goals. Two important ideas here are that of **interpolation** and **regression**. The former matches your data exactly (hence will have perfect training accuracy), and the latter attempts to minimize some sort of error (e.g. the linear regression you tried). While interpolation would solve your problem, it typically lacks the ability to **generalize**, which seems to be something you care about given the use of a train/test split. Most machine learning models **are not perfect**, so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Increasing the size of the data set would at least deal with the negative score issue. For that problem, I'd expect a score of around 0.4 for a linear regression with enough data so that you don't overfit to the training set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Hans Musgrave. I tried using GaussianNB it seems to be giving the score of 1.0 for almost all the records except one or two with 0.5 score. If you prefer any other algorithm please let me know I will give it a try.

Comment: With so little data and no domain information, I don't really have a favorite algorithm. One thing to point out though, because of the repeated [1,2,1,1] with different y-values you'll never be able to hit perfect accuracy. Additionally, all of the predictive power exists in the second coordinate. You could get rid of the 1st, 3rd, and 4th coordinates without any drop in accuracy.